# Postgresql, how to sync the data of the Docker and the host?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following two ideas.

> use -v to sync the data file

I didn't find the data file, i look up the `postgresql.conf`, it shows the data in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`.But i saw the file which is vary small while my data is much bigger.

> use `-p`, to let docker use the host database for additions and deletions.

When i ry this, it returns 5432 is in use.Because my other progress is using postgres.

So,what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The 'basic' command to start a postgres.

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

This will just start a postgres container with default user postgres and password mysecretpassword. This DB-container is'nt persistent which means that a reboot of the machine or restarting the container can cause a loss of data.

By default the data of postgres will be stored in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. You can define your own path by using the environment variable `PGDATA` in your run command. Check [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) for more info.

So to make your data persistent we need to mount the data from `/var/lib/postgresql/data` of your container to your host. Here for we use the `-v` option.

First we need to create a directory or a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) on your host. This will be the place to which we mount our data. I will use a directory in my example (most basic). So on your host:

```
mkdir -p /var/my-data
```

Now you can stop your old container and recreate one using the `-v` flag to persist the data.

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -v /var/my-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

The data of `/var/lib/postgresql/data` will be mounted to `/var/my-data` on your host. So when you delete your postgres container the data will still be on your host machine in `/var/my-data` and you will be able to reuse it.

If you want to copy data from the postgres on your host to the postgres-docker you need to copy the data of your original postgres (probably in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` to `/var/my-data`. Letting them both use the same path to the data will probably cause corruptions so you have to duplicate it.

The `-p` option means `"map your container-port on the host port"`. So you can access your real postgresDB probably on port `5432`. The default port. Your postgres-docker container will expose `5432` on its container but you can not access it from outside your server. With the use of `-p` you can map your container port `5432` on a host port (for example `5433`). You'll docker run command will look like this:

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -v /var/my-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```